# jQuery .getJSON not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I'm just learning how to utilise ajax/json with jquery and I've hit a brick wall that I just don't understand.

Here is my code - VERY simple code:

```
$("#click").click(function() {
    $.getJSON("http://localhost/jsontest/a.json", function(data) {
        alert("done"); 
    });

   });
```

Basically, load a.json and send an alert to the screen saying done.

Here are the contents of a.json:

{ "done": "37" }

That's it.

It doesn't work though... the alert is not displayed.

Any ideas folks?

Comment: http://livehttpheaders.mozdev.org is your friend.

Comment: What is the url of the page making the request?

Comment: well it's a JSON "get" so that shouldn't be a problem ...

Comment: Are you sure that the element you want to be able to click is really named "click"?  (I've spent an embarrassing amount of time finding problems like that!)

Comment: @Pointy - `$.getJSON()` is an AJAX request, it's not JSONP an still subject to same-origin policy rules...

Comment: Oo oo and are you sure that you're doing the above code in a "ready"  or "load" handler?

Comment: @Nick umm I don't think that's true - `$.getJSON` forces the "dataType" property to be "json", so jQuery bypasses XHR and does the script trick.

Comment: @Pointy - That's not true in this case, that's only if the url or data has (`callback=?`), you can try it: http://jsfiddle.net/5TQ7G/ Look at Firebug or Chrome for a quick glance, you'll see it's a XHR request, or look at the headers: `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest`, you can't add headers to a JSONP request (that's one of the main reasons it's allowed), in any case it's not doing the script trick...how could it?  It would be `<script>{ "done": "37" }</script>`, JSONP has to be: `<script>callbackFunc({ "done": "37" })</script>`, you'll just get an error without the server piece doing that.

Comment: Yea, you're right; `getJSON` sets the type to "json", not "jsonp"; if it were the latter then "callback=?" would be added automatically. I've done jsonp but never via jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm betting on this: you forgot to put that setup code in a `<script>` block *after* your "click" element, or in a "ready" handler:

```
$(function() {
  $('#click').click(function() { /* ... same stuff as you have ... */ });
});
```

Answer (score 9):

I just had an issue where I didn't format the data in the file that it's retrieving right.  If the JSON in the file has anything wrong with it, it fails silently.  Though you can always add .fail(function) to detect the fail.

I was using: `{ varname:"my string" }`

When I should have been using: `{ "varname":"mystring" }`

For this reason I think it might be better to use get to retrieve the data with $.get() and then use JSON.parse() on it.  This way you know whether the get or the parse failed.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any error returned from firebug?

I'd start by changing:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/jsontest/a.json?callback=?", function(data) {
```

to:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/jsontest/a.json", 'callback=?', function(data) {
```

Comment: No errors returned from Firefox - I tried it with ...a.json?callback=? - still never worked.

It works now - the alert(data.done) did the trick.

Thanks guys :-)

Comment: So when you said "the alert is not displayed", you meant, "the alert happens but it just contains the word 'done'"?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.getJSON("http://localhost/jsontest/a.json", { }, function(data) {
    alert(data.done);
});
```

Comment: That is not necessary. If jQuery sees that the second parameter is a function, it assumes that the call looks like the call in the original question.

Comment: +1 - The ` { },` portion is not needed, the callback can be the second param, but the `alert(data.done)` (instead of the string `"done"`) is correct.

Comment: Well yes, but he says the alert is not displayed.  @Nick you're the acknowledged master of spotting "forgot to put code in a 'ready' handler" problems!!